# Disable/Enable secure logon on windows 7 via commandline

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script

In windows you can disable the usage of ctrl+alt+delete before logging in.
{Via netplwiz or user controlpasswords2 then advanced will give you a window with at the bottom of it this option}.
Is there any possibility that this is able to be done using cmd or powershell?
I have been looking for a solution for about 3 weeks without any success.

Answer (score 3):

From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978776.aspx): You need to change the registry value

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DisableCAD`

- 0 means *Users must press CTRL+ALT+DEL to log on to the system.* or
- 1 means *Users need not press CTRL+ALT+DEL to log on to the system.*

Registry values can be set by `reg.exe` (via cmd.exe) or with built-in mechanisms in PowerShell (`Set-Location`, `Set-ItemProperty`).

Comment: Don't hate on me but I have no idea how to interprete this comment. You give a UNC path starting with HKLM, which is not defined and I have no idea where it would come from. I am fairly new to scripting.

Comment: @Jonathan - Your last comment does not make sense, `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\`, is a fairly common location for stuff like `DisableCAD`

Comment: @Jonathan: HKLM is a commonly used abbreviation for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` which you'll find in regedit.

Comment: @Jonathan Given the fact that you have not enough knowledge to know that HKLM stands for, could you please explain what is the reason you need a scriptable solution to change the secure logon? I'ld expect only admins to need a script to change that. Users could just do it via system control applets.

Answer (score 0):

To enable Ctrl Alt Del logon Screen,
run form cmd "reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "DisableCAD" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f"

To disable Ctrl Alt Del logon Screen,
run from cmd "reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "DisableCAD" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f"

If "AutoAdminLogon" exists in this registry path,
run from cmd "reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "AutoAdminLogon" /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f"